# How can I download Ubuntu securely?

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to download ubuntu desktop securely.

This is the link on the ubuntu.com website:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04.2/ubuntu-14.04.2-desktop-i386.iso

And here is the SHA256 hash link:
http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/SHA256SUMS

Problem is, both these links are http, and the ubuntu.com server doesn't seem to support https.  Is there any way I can download the .iso securely?

Comment: Use BitTorrent with required encryption.

Comment: Why do you need it? Do you want to hide the fact of downloading or what? Checksum is enough to be sure nothing has changed.

Comment: HTTPS or another secure way of transfering would protect you from anyone knowing that you downloaded Ubuntu and the checksum. In order to avoid manipulated downloads (it'd be necessary to manipulate both) you have to protect yourself against man-in-the-middle attacks on the client side.

Comment: HTTPS MD5 hashes are available [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Comment: @Pilot6 - I need it to ensure that the .iso is the one officially released by ubuntu.  Plain http requests allow a 'man in the middle' to change the .iso file on the fly easily.  Unfortunately the same problem applies to the checksum - if I cannot obtain it over https then I cannot trust that is has not been tampered with.

Comment: @DougSmythies - thank you, but unfortunately MD5 hashes are not cryptographically secure.  Ideally I'm looking to obtain the SHA256 hash over https.

Comment: Another problem is when using Firefox https addons. The https://www.ubuntu.com/download as well as man pages are just keep loading indefinitely. Then I realize it is because of https.

Comment: @the_Seppi Even with bittorrent, a MITM attacker could give you a bad torrent file.

Answer (score 2):

The key fingerprints are on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VerifyIsoHowto

Currently they are

```
C598 6B4F 1257 FFA8 6632  CBA7 4618 1433 FBB7 5451
8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
```

You can retrieve them both with:

```
gpg --recv-key 843938DF228D22F7B3742BC0D94AA3F0EFE21092 C5986B4F1257FFA86632CBA746181433FBB75451
```

If you're already on an Ubuntu system the package `ubuntu-keyring` has these keys in `/usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg` which you can import with `gpg --import /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg`.

Comment: This also works from Debian 8, apparently. (And thank you!)